# Mapping gRPC error codes to HTTP error codes

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, nginx-reverse-proxy, grpc-python

My web-application makes HTTP requests to an [Extensible Service Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/frameworks-extensible-service-proxy#extensible_service_proxy) (ESP), which in-turn, delegates to a [gRPC server](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html) (written in Python). Ignoring Android and iOS clients, the architecture is:

[image]

The ESP is a [nginx reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/).

The gRPC server ("Your code" in the reference architecture) may raise an exception, in which case I use [context.abort](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.ServicerContext.abort) to raise an exception and terminate the RPC with a non-OK status:

```
try:
  # Do something that could fail.
except ValueError as e:
  context.abort(grpc.StatusCode.DATA_LOSS, str(e))
```

While it is possible to use [set_code](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.ServicerContext.set_code) and [set_details](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.ServicerContext.set_details), they still result in a HTTP status of 200 OK.

There are two problems:

1. The [gRPC status codes](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/statuscodes.md) are translated by the ESP container (nginx proxy) to a a generic `500 Internal Server Error`.
2. The accompanying details are stripped-out.
3. and 2. combined means the web client has, at most, a `500 Internal Server Error` for *all* exceptions raised by the gRPC server.

Ultimately, I don't understand how more informative (ideally, custom) errors can be returned to web-clients.

Answer (score 5):

grpc Status code::DATA_LOSS, are translated to HTTP code 500. The code is [here](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/master/src/api_manager/utils/status.cc#L320)

The grpc status detail (status code and error message) are send back in the response body in JSON format.  The code is [here](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/master/src/nginx/error.cc#L213)